# Testing PHP code in dreamweaver

Tags: php, testing, dreamweaver

I'm currently developing a simple web based application which is using HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript. I'm developing this with Adobe Dreamweaver 3.0 and I have used procedural PHP in writing server side scripting. Now, I want to test the PHP codes. Can someone tell me how can I test the procedural PHP code in dreamweaver?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_testing_server.html

Comment: Do you have PHP, and a server, installed?

Answer (score 0):

You need install a webserver and php in your computer to test localy your site. I recomend you XAMPP.

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

It's the easy way to install all that you need.

Comment: This is an assignment and I need to show the test cases for the instructor. How can I do that? I have already installed XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

To run your code you need a server installed in your machine. After successfully installing the server your need to start that server. To check is your server working? Open a browser and type `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Also you need to put your php file inside the server DocumentRoot Folder In **Xammp server** it located here `C:\xampp\htdocs\` In **Vertrigo server** it located here `C:\VertrigoServ\www\`

**It will display the localhost page like this.**

[image: show localhost page]

In **Xampp Server**
[image: Xampp server page]

In **Vertigo Server**
[image: vertrigo server page]

Comment: This is an assignment and I need to show the test cases for the instructor. How can I do that? I have already installed XAMPP. What I want to do is something like PHPunit. But I don't know what to do.

Comment: Made a folder inside the DocumentRoot and run as support you made a folder like this "PHPunit" then you need to run it as http://localhost/PHPunit/

Comment: Can I write unit test cases using dreamweaver environment?