# Writing unit test cases in dreamweaver 3.0

Tags: php, testing, dreamweaver

I'm currently developing a simple web based application which is using HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript. I'm developing this with Adobe Dreamweaver 3.0 and I have used procedural PHP in writing server side scripting. Now I want to test the program. I have already test it using XAMPP localhost. As this is an assignment, now we have to write test cases and show them to our instructor. **Can I write unit test cases in dreamweaver 3.0 to test my program?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing PHP code in dreamweaver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977439/testing-php-code-in-dreamweaver)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't get a good answer on whether I can use dreamweaver to write unit test cases. That's why I post it again.